# error line expected length x1 x2 y2 y2 and transform d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I develop an application web where I'm using lib d3 and javascript which is display a graph with nodes. 
I implemented a search bar which is not working well all the time.
Sometimes it's not recover the position from the node. 
and I have an error :

```
Error: <line> attribute x1: Expected length, "NaN"
Error: <line> attribute y1: Expected length, "NaN".
Error: <line> attribute x2: Expected length, "NaN".
Error: <line> attribute y2: Expected length, "NaN".
Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN,NaN)".
```

and the node stay stuck on the corner of the window. 
I specify when I am using the search bar, I delete the actual graph for the new with the search.

```
myWidget.svg = myWidget.d3.select(myWidget.homeViewWrapper)
                      .append("svg")
                      .attr("width", myWidget.width)
                      .attr("height", myWidget.height)
                      .append("g")
                      //TODO zoom !
                      .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + 0 + ")")
                      .append("g")
                      .attr("transform", "translate("+ 0 +","+ 0+ ")")
                      .attr("class", "container")
                      .call(chart);
myWidget.homeViewWrapper.inject(widget.body);

myWidget.links.attr("x1", function(d) {return d.source.x;})
        .attr("y1", function(d) {return d.source.y;})
        .attr("x2", function(d) {return d.target.x;})
        .attr("y2", function(d) {return d.target.y;})
myWidget.node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(myWidget.status_radius, Math.min(myWidget.width - myWidget.status_radius, d.x)); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(myWidget.status_radius, Math.min(myWidget.height - myWidget.status_radius, d.y));});
myWidget.node.attr("transform", function(d){return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";});
```

Comment: It looks like the `x` and `y` attributes of your `node` attribute are undefined. You can log them to the console by changing your functions a little: `.attr('y2', function (d) { console.log(d); return d.source.y; })`, then check the object there!

Comment: @RubenHelsloot yes I think too, but why it's not working just sometimes.. I don't understand

Comment: Just have a look in the browser console, whenever it doesn't work, look at the values the node or link had at that point

Comment: @RubenHelsloot it's return NAN when it doesn't work and when it's works it's the position from the node

Comment: Does the node the link corresponds to change at any moment? Do you insert or remove nodes? Can you create a JSFiddle with the working code?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot yes I insert a node for a searching data but I  refresh the page